# Kino Flo: should I buy 4 fixtures with one ballast? Would I need anything else?

Tags: lighting, lighting-modifiers

Not much experience with Kino Flos...

Considering buying 4x of these: [Kino Flo 4Bank 4' Fixture Only](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/258311-REG/Kino_Flo_CFX_4804_4Bank_4_Fixture_Only.html)

And am wondering if I could get away with only one ballast: [Kino Flo Mega 4Bank DMX Ballast (120V)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/393671-REG/Kino_Flo_BAL_450_M120_Mega_4Bank_DMX_Ballast.html)

Would I need additional connectors, cables or anything else in order to use the four fixtures with the selected ballast?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can determine, you need one ballast per 4Bank (one ballast channel per lamp, four lamps per bank) and one cable to connect the two. So for four 4Bank fixtures, you need four ballast units and four cables.

See the [4Bank page](http://www.kinoflo.com/Lighting%20fixtures%20with%20Remote%20ballast/4Bank,%20Double,%20Single/4bank%20select/4Bank.htm) at kinoflow.com for more.

Comment: Thank you. So I need one ballast for every bank. That's expensive.